# MySQL: Fixing Unique key constraint violation

Tags: mysql, data-integrity

I have a database with an unique key constraint.

When I import this database from a dump created by mysqldump I get

```
'14698-3' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGS EARCH_FULLTEXT_PRODUCT_ID_STORE_ID'
```

But when I check the database where the export was generated, the constraint violation is not visible:

```
mysql> select count(*) from catalogsearch_fulltext where product_id = 14698 and store_id = 3;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
```

I suppose that MySQL does not show the second entry, because it uses the index.

How can I show this entry and fix it easily on the live system?

Comment: maybe `mysqlshow -kp base table` or `SHOW INDEX FROM table FROM db;` no so sure anyway...